# How to use Zend_View_Helper Navigation Links

Tags: zend-framework, hyperlink

I want to add to my template of my site the  for pagination. My site is on Zend Framework. I  find that I can use  Zend_View_Helper Navigation Links and the example

```
Render only start, next, and prev:
$helper->setRenderFlag(Zend_View_Helper_Navigation_Links::RENDER_START |
                       Zend_View_Helper_Navigation_Links::RENDER_NEXT |
                       Zend_View_Helper_Navigation_Links::RENDER_PREV);
```

But the problem is that I cant understand how to use it. Can some body give me an example o a small explanation what I need to do please?

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you rather check out the pagination of Zend Framework:

http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.paginator.usage.html

If you are looking for a way to step through a dataset, this will help you more than the navigation helper.

Edit: After the comment- You have to add the relevant "rel" or "rev" to the container ie,

```
$container = new Zend_Navigation(array(
    array(
        'label' => 'Relations using strings',
        'rel'   => array(
            'next' => 'http://www.example.org/'
        ),
        'rev'   => array(
            'prev' => 'http://www.example.net/'
        )
    ),
);
```

then in the viewscript:

```
<?php echo $this->view->navigation()->links(); ?>
```

Hope this is better.

Comment: Hi, thank you for the answer, but I have pagination on my site and I want to add <link rel="next" href="..." /> for SEO